# How do I get Notification Icons to follow my Icon theme?

Tags: themes, icons, gnome-panel

Basically I am using AwOken icon set and the notification area shows different icons than that of awoken i.e colored tray icon. What can I do to bring in consistency or similarity? I found [this](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/11/use-ubuntu-mono-icons-with-any-icon-theme/) and [this](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/09/how-to-use-ubuntu-mono-panel-icons-with-others-icon-sets/) but both did not help.

[image: notification area]

Comment: Does the icon set you are using provide any replacement icons for those applications?

Comment: I dont know about replacement but they seem to have consistency on application menu. Basically Gnote and synapse icon on the above panel picture are what awoken themes should look like. I was wondering if I could bring same consistency for other tray icons ? I hope that I am clear on my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An icon theme can only replace icons it was planed to replace. If your icon theme does not provide replacement icons for applications which are not initially part of Ubuntu like Skype, VLC and XChat for example then you'll either have to find appropriate icons somewhere and replace them manually or you will have to create them yourself.